# decompiler for VSTO file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, outlook-addin

I lost the code I developed for one Outlook addin and the only file I have is the VSTO. Any software to decompile?

Answer (score 1):

If the code is not obfuscated you may use [reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) to decompile it. Reflector gets as input the dll (this is the vsto file) and shows you the source code.

The result is not 100% your code, but you get all your classes and almost all the structure of the project (depends on project structure).

Comment: I have reflector and I used it to decompile my other lost code (.cs files), however, it is not accepting vsto and even the executable file for this outlook addin is not opening (error message: .exe is not a .NET module)!!

Comment: I thought your code is .Net code. Reflector decompiles only .Net.

Comment: The weird thing is that it is .net (C#) and I used Visual Studio 10.

Comment: if is c#, reflector should work. Are you sure you use the correct file? The file should be a dll!

Comment: I tried both files setup.exe and the .VSTO deployment file with no luck!

Comment: Are you sure you decompile your code? If is your code you should have the dll. If is not your code, install the addon, find the installation place (usually in Program Files, under some developer folder), find the dll (or more) and decompile it. This will success only if the dll is .Net and not obfuscated! Happy hacking!

Comment: The setup.exe is the installer. Install it first then go to the selected installation directory and decompile the dlls you find there

Answer (score 1):

Look inside your Application folder (the folder you published your vsto file) for a file called YourProgram.dll.deploy and then make a copy of it. Once it is copied rename the file to remove the .deploy and then look at the YourProgram.dll file with any .Net decompiler and you should be able to see your source code.

Replace YourProgram with your actual program name.